# How can I move a tcolorbox to the right side of the page?

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to have my tcolorbox, which is smaller than the surrounding running text, be positioned towards the right page margin. Is there a way to do this?

I've included my current MWE and a screenshot of what I mean for clarity:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\newtcolorbox{importantbox}[2][]{
  width=0.9\textwidth,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=yellow, 
  coltitle=black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  title=\faIcon{exclamation-triangle}~Caution: #2,#1
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{importantbox}{Lorem Ipsum}
   \lipsum
\end{importantbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: what I'm trying to do with the tcolorbox]

Comment: Please note: It would be better, if the image you show would be the result of the code you show, which is not the case. Your code produces a too large box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use options `before` and `after` to print it inside a `flushright` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\newtcolorbox{importantbox}[2][]{
  before=\begin{flushright},
  after=\end{flushright},
  width=0.9\textwidth,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=yellow, 
  coltitle=black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  title=\faIcon{exclamation-triangle}~Caution: #2,#1
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{importantbox}{Lorem Ipsum}
   \lipsum[3]
\end{importantbox}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: For centering you can use `center` instead of `flushright`.

Almost the same, but with less vertical space above and below, can be done using option `flush right`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{mwe}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\newtcolorbox{importantbox}[2][]{
  flush right,
  width=0.9\textwidth,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=yellow, 
  coltitle=black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  title=\faIcon{exclamation-triangle}~Caution: #2,#1
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{importantbox}{Lorem Ipsum}
   \lipsum[3]
\end{importantbox}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you don't want the extra vertical space above and below, you can alternatively use `before=\hfill` or `before=\hspace*{\fill}`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{mwe}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\newtcolorbox{importantbox}[2][]{
  before=\hfill,
  width=0.9\textwidth,
  colback=white, 
  colframe=yellow, 
  coltitle=black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  title=\faIcon{exclamation-triangle}~Caution: #2,#1
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{importantbox}{Lorem Ipsum}
   \lipsum[3]
\end{importantbox}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That's super helpful! Sorry about the image, I must have uploaded a shot from an old compilation attempt by accident orz.

Comment: @MadyYuvi sorry, I was called away for a work meeting and couldn't finish responding earlier

Comment: @serval Nothing serious, no need to say sorry, cheers